# JQ: Codepage Errors after transformation

Tags: json, utf-8, jq

I use JQ to transform a json file from a Germany, for a later DB Import. As far i understand supports JQ UTF-8. I checked the original json file with Notepad++ and the Codepage Shows UTF-8 without BOM. 
After Transformation with jq i checked the new json file and there are a lot of Code Errors where in the original file stands ä,Ö,ß and all that stuff. 
How can i transform data without that Errors?
I use JQ 1.5 for Windows (64 bit) downloaded around two weeks from the Github release site

I use following jq Statement:

```
jq "[{nid, title, nights, zone: .zones[0].title} + (.sails[] | { sails_nid: .nid, arrival, departure } ) + (.sails[].cabins[] | { cabintype: .cabinType.kindName, catalogPrice, discountPrice, discountPercentage, currency } )]"  dreamlines_details.json >test.json
```

here is the original data:
[original data](https://codeshare.io/5ePZpK)

here are one result set:
[results](https://codeshare.io/5wyJA9)

Comment: Please be more specific about the JSON input, the jq filter, and the version of jq you are using.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi @Peak i added the the jq command, Version and linked the original data and the result data.

Comment: You seem to be experiencing a Windows-related issue. Please see https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html and report the output produced by: jq -V

Comment: Hi @Peak, jq -V produced following Output: jq-1.5   I also checked the chcp Code. Active Codepage was 850. I changed it with chcp in the runtime to 65001 (UTF8) but reveived still wrong data. I transfered the command to Powershell (since the better Unicode Support) but receive there also wrong data

Comment: I have verified that jq 1.5 produces the expected results in a Windows 10 environment, both using the default code page on the machine (437) or 65001.  The German-specific characters appear normally both on-screen and when redirected to a file.  The jq executable was obtained using chocolatey (https://chocolatey.org/packages/jq)

Comment: Hi @Peak, thanks for your Feedback. I found the error. I look only in the source data not in my test data (where i test the jq Transformation). For any reason the Codepage was there another than in the original sources. With the original sources the Codepage error did not happen. Thanks for your Support. Regards Timo

Comment: The results link takes you to an empty code share.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me just fine in Linux. I'd recommend using [Bash for Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) and installing jq and trying again. Also, be sure to use single quotes around your filter statement.